# Kirchoff's current law - unable to understand (possibly) simple transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

I suspect it must be something very simple but for the life of me I cannot figure out how from the below (which models a circuit of two resistors connected in parallel)
$$i=v\left(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}\right)$$
we get to the following
$$v=i\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2})}$$
I suspect we get an intermittent step of
$$\frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{i}\left(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}\right)$$
but how do we flip it over to obtain just the final form?

Comment: You just reciprocate. What is $1/(1/i)$, just $i$ and the resistor values just remain in that form.

Comment: You have $a = bc$ in the first equality. You have $b = a/c$ in the second. So to get from the first to the second you divide both sides by $1/R_1 + 1/R_2$. Right?

Comment: If $ax=b$, then you have $x = \frac{b}{a}$.

Comment: I see now, Marek, you are spot on. I didn't realize I could do the reciprocate bit as outlined by Amzoti (as I didn't realize $\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{y}$ is the same as $x=y$ and also somehow I was not seeing that we can do it the other way around as you suggest Marek, that is instead of dividing by $i$ and dividing by $v$ we can go straight to dividing by $(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2})$, thank you so much!!! :) It has been quite a while since I have done math at school hence sometimes simple things trip me over...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I can obtain the final form by dividing both sides of
$$i=v(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2})$$
by
$$(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2})$$
or alternatively if I start with dividing both sides by $v$ and then by $i$ and obtain
$$\frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{i}\left(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2}\right)$$ 
I can just flip the numerators and denominators since if I have
$$\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{b}$$ if I reciprocate (or flip the numerator with the denominator on both sides) the equality still holds
$$a=b$$
Either way I arrive at 
$$v=i\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R2})}$$
Seem a bit silly now for asking the question but thank you very much for all your help! :) Somehow couldn't see this on my own.